# How to stop posts status resetting to Published

Tags: custom-post-types

I have custom post types and custom statuses registered. The post status is updated from a custom drop down box that I have inserted into a metabox on the edit post screen.

It works fine, however when I update a post without changing the status via the custom drop down, the post status resets back to Published. So it seems that if either the Publish button is pressed when creating a post, or the Update button is pressed when editing the post status always defaults to published...

Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Please show your `save_post` action.

Comment: I adjusted the way in which I am working and switched from "publishing" a post to simply saving it and all is now working as expected... thank you